# Check if RabbitMQ service program is running/connected to RPC Queue

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, rabbitmq, message-queue

Background

I am developing a service program in c# that will take a request from a c# aspx .net web app, process the request and send progress messages back to the web app.  That basics of this process are working, but as I have come to understand, with RPC messaging, if the service program is down and the web app makes a request, that request hangs as there is no acknowledgment.

I did put in code to clear/purge the rpcqueue on start up of the web app and service program, but in testing, when I intentionally drop the service program and send a request, the web app hangs.

Question

I am looking for a way to test, on the web app side, if the service program is up and running *before* sending a request.  I tried checking on the connection, but that just creates a connection on the web app side.  I tried checking the rpcqueue, but the web app also creates that if missing.

This is the code that sends the RPC request and waits for the Ack and this is what hangs if the service program is not running:

```
        private async Task<string> InvokeAsync(string n)
    {
        //var rpcClient = new RpcClient();
       // RpcClient.CheckRabbitMQStatus();

        //Console.WriteLine(" [x] Requesting fib({0})", n);
        var response = await RpcClient.CallAsync(n);
        lblAcknowledged.Text = $"{response}";
        warning.Text = $"{response}";

        //Console.WriteLine(" [.] Got '{0}'", response);

        return response;
    }
```

I thought that I could remove the await and maybe use an event and check on the timer and if too long, error the process, but could not find how to attach an event to the CallAsync.  If I cannot make RPC queue'ing resilient I may resort to simple queue and try a threaded wait with a timer.

I am hoping someone has use RabbitMQ this way and solved how to check if the consumer of an RPC message is able to receive.